# Japanese in text object

Tags: text-object

I can't seem to type or paste Japanese characters into a text object. Is there a way or is is this just a known deficiency or bug? ありがとう。 Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you just need to select a font that has japanese characters. I downloaded NotoSansJP-Regular font and it seems to work just fine. With Text object selected in Object Data Properties (The a tab) under Font you can select the font you want to use.

[image: Japanese font]

Comment: Thanks - it was actually a combination of issues. The font I had DID have Japanese characters, but seems damaged. When I tried another it was fine.  The text had to be pasted in (I assume you did that) It would not accept (ignored)  typed input. Not ideal, but workable. Thought I had tried another font, but I guess not - thanks for idea.

Comment: also I think you need a certain format (OTF?)